# Issues with Multi Indexing in a pandas data frame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Hello I have data in the format shown below[image]

I am trying to perform some data munging on this data set whose column index (first level) spans several months. As an instance If I just need the first month information, I proceed to do the following. But it just keeps erring out and the documentation is not really helping me. I have tried many times now.

```
    VolData = pd.read_excel(VolDataFilePath,sheetname=r'BaseFwdVols',header=[0,1],index_col=None)
IndexList = ['SPTR','SPTRMDCP','NDDUEAFE','RU20INTR','AGGBOND','HYBOND']

Test = VolData.loc[:,(slice(1),IndexList)]
```

It keeps erring out with the message below:`

```
`KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (1)'
```

What am I missing here?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried `VolData.sort_index(axis=1, level=0)` prior to attempting your slicing? I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to sort your `MultiIndex`. Here's a quick example I put together:

```
df

foo     b                         a               
b       5     4      3     1      3      2       1
a                                                 
abc   NaN  47.0    NaN  45.0  243.0    NaN   123.0
def   NaN   NaN  456.0   NaN    NaN    NaN  1176.0
ghb   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN  567.0     NaN
lop  12.0   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
mno   NaN   NaN   87.0   NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
```

Notice the Column multiindex is ordered descending.

Attempting this gives me an error:

```
df.loc[:, ('b', [5,4])]
KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'
```

The fix:

```
df.sort_index(axis=1).loc[:, ('b', [5,4])]
foo     b      
b       4     5
a              
abc  47.0   NaN
def   NaN   NaN
ghb   NaN   NaN
lop   NaN  12.0
mno   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: First up Thanks. I will give it a try. There is a thing that confounds me though. I was under the impression that loc[.] should act like a dictionary lookup. Why is sorting a prerequisite for using the Loc attribute?? Thanks again.

Comment: @schuler I'm definitely not an expert in this area but my understanding is searching a `MultiIndex` uses `np.searchsorted`. If the index is not sorted performance will be seriously affected. This type of error previously came up as `PerformanceWarning`.

Comment: @schuler Please do accept as answer if this helped!

Comment: IT worked. I will march ahead with your fix until some one who knows whats happening enlighten me on this peculiar behavior.

Comment: This may be helpful- http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/advanced.html